# Sorting an array and linking changes to another array of identical size

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

i am trying to sort an array of strings which are terms of a polynomial. every position is 1 term of the polynomial as a string, and signed approapriately, however i want to sort them in order by the power.

eg

+3x^5
+5
-8x
-4x^2

how i have approached this is by creating a second array  storing just the power, and i want to sort them both based off this array. ie

```
for (int i=0; i<sortArray.length; i++) {
        if (sortArray[i].indexOf("^")!= -1) 
            sortArrayDegree[i] = Integer.parseInt((sortArray[i].
                  substring(sortArray[i].indexOf("^") + 1, sortArray[i].length())));
        else if (sortArray[i].indexOf("x")!= -1)    
            sortArrayDegree[i]=1;
        else 
            sortArrayDegree[i]=0;
    }
```

however i am not sure how to link the two, so any changes to the second happen to the first

currently that means the second array looks like this
5
0
1
2
i thought i could make a new array and store this as the second column(clash of data types), but that still leaves the sorting problem

Comment: How is the polynomial represented? As an array of Strings? As two arrays? Without this information, it is impossible to properly answer the question.

Comment: the polynomial is stored as a singly linked list containing coefficient and power in each node, but in preparation for converting back from singly linked list to a string and sorting each term, i have broken it into seperate terms stored in a 1D array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that the way you want achieve this is the wisest way, but this is how you could do it:
Create a class of both the `power` and the `number` of the polynomial member. Make that class `Comparable`, then put it in one array and the sort method will use the comparable method you have overridden from the `Comparable` interface.

```
public class PolynomialMember implements Comparable<PolynomialMember> {

    public int power; // public for brevity, but should be private with getters and setters
    public String number; // public for brevity, but should be private with getters and setters

    public PolynomialMember(String number, int power) {
        this.number = number;
        this.power = power;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PolynomialMember o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.power, o.power);
    }

    // optional: override for pretty printing
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(!number.equals("0")) {
            if(number.charAt(0) == '-') {
                return number + "x^" + power;
            } else {
                return "+" + number + "x^" + power;
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

this way you don't need two arrays, and you certainly shouldn't "link" two arrays.

You can use this class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<PolynomialMember> polynom = new ArrayList<PolynomialMember>();
    polynom.add(new PolynomialMember("-5", 3));
    polynom.add(new PolynomialMember("7", 1));
    polynom.add(new PolynomialMember("4", 0));
    polynom.add(new PolynomialMember("8", 2));

    for(PolynomialMember pm : polynom) {
        System.out.print(pm + " ");
        // prints: -5x^3 +7x^1 +4x^0 +8x^2 
    }
    System.out.println();
    Collections.sort(polynom); //this is where the magic happens.
    for(PolynomialMember pm : polynom) {
        System.out.print(pm + " ");
        // prints: +4x^0 +7x^1 +8x^2 -5x^3 
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, now that you mention doing it like this, the polynomail is actually stored as a singly linked list, is it possible to sort a singly linked list by one of the terms that a node stores?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I've tried showing here. It would work with a `LinkedList` as well (it will work with any sortable collection from the collections package), but be warned that sorting a `LinkedList` is more expensive than sorting an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Ideally you would be putting them in a `TreeSet` really,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, which I'm really not sure, you want to bind the data of 2 arrays containing value types\immutables. The easiest way i know to bind data from 2 arrays is to create a class containing both of them as private members and exposing public methods to control them. in these methods you could implement the logic that defines the relationship between them.